# Getting MongoDB working with GeoServer 2

Tags: geoserver, geotools, mongodb

I'm trying to use MongoDB with GeoServer but it is actually not working at all.
Someone once posted this: [Getting MongoDB Working with GeoServer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35284/getting-mongodb-working-with-geoserver), but since he could solve his problem without any help there's not much info about how I can do it too.

I got the MongoDB GeoTools plugin (what is the correct .jar file and on which folder should I put it?). I'm trying to make the "new data source" option appear like this guy did.

If someone could help me in a "tutorial like" way I'ld be very happy :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

download gt-mongodb,like gt-mongodb-9.2.jar and put the file at: apache-tomcat-6.0.30\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\lib . 
download mongo for java ,like mongo-2.9.1.jar . 
add it to classpath ,such as C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.30\lib\mongo-2.9.1.jar .
and restart your computer and start your tomcat.
you will see the mongodb at geoserver->stores.

Answer (score 1):

To install geoserver plugins, make sure you put them to the `lib` of `WEB-INF` (e.g. `webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib` ) not
the lib in geoserver (i.e. `/usr/share/geoserver/lib`).