# How to publish the layer from MongoDB store in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, geotools, mongodb

I am using GeoServer 2.5, MongoDB 2.4 Windows 7 64 bit

I am imported JSON data file into MongoDB using the below query.

```
mongoimport --db GeoMongodb --collection states  --file E:/states.json --jsonArray
```

This query successfully created states table into MongoDB database.

I am created MongoDB store in GeoServer. The store also created but inserted MongoDB spatial table not showing in MongoDB store as layer in GeoServer.
([Getting MongoDB working with GeoServer 2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54950/getting-mongodb-working-with-geoserver-2))
I referred to this link for creating MongoDB store, so I checked GeoServer log, and it is showing like this error:

> 2014-04-17 14:22:32,723 ERROR [data.mongodb] - getLayers error;
>   command failed [mapreduce]: { "serverUsed" :
>   "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017" , "errmsg" : "exception: ReferenceError:
>   mapfields_recursive is not defined near 'ction() { mapfields_recursive
>   (\"\", this);' " , "code" : 16722 , "ok" : 0.0}

Can you please give me the steps for publishing layer from MongoDB store like postgres database?

Answer (score 1):

you can use Mongodb Plugin(gt-mongodb) that exists in **GeoTools** 17
http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/mongodb.html