# Working with GeoServer and MongoDB

Tags: geoserver, error, mongodb, configuration

I am trying to get MongoDB working with GeoServer. I am using the BoundlessGeo Suite (comes with GeoServer and other tools) I was able to find the MongoDB extension for GeoServer. Got it installed according to these instructions:

[Getting MongoDB Working with GeoServer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35284/getting-mongodb-working-with-geoserver)

I found this version of the extension:
http://repo.opengeo.org/org/geotools/gt-mongodb/12-SNAPSHOT/

I am able to see MongoDB as an option in the Data Store Menu. MongoDB is also installed on the server locally for testing. I was able to create a database without much issue.

After putting in the Data Store Settings, I attempt to upload a shapefile using GeoExplorer when I get the following error:

"Name is required for PropertyType"

When I searched for the error I found almost no results but what I did find seemed to indicate that I needed to make an XML file to designate where the Mongo Info is. I would just have no idea about what needs to go in that file or where it needs to go.

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/app-schema/mapping-file.html

Kind of stuck and wondering if anybody else out there was able to get it to work on any of their setup.